# Mount a possibly unfinalized data disc (DVD) on lubuntu 20.04 for normal usual usage

Tags: mount, 20.04, dvd

I was a windows user long ago, and at time I had burned some study materials on DVDs for future use. I had burnt them on a Windows 7 machine using the windows disc burner. That machine is still there with me but the HDD was replaced, so though it contains Windows 7, the corresponding data maintaining the particular discs (if at all) in the older HDD is no longer there on the replaced HDD. Now all the DVDs are readable on Windows 7 (newer HDD).(So clearly there is no dependence on the directory structure of the disk being maintained on HDD). The Windows 7 machine has got old and dusty and it is not quite usable without a thorough clean of the connector and all (switches off due to thermal issue within few minutes of usage).

I currently use Lubuntu 20.04 on my current stable machine. Almost all the discs mount automatically and I can read the data on them without any issues. Now few discs do not mount automatically on Lubuntu (however there is no issue with them on the Windows 7 machine). The drive just not shown in the the "computer" section of Lubuntu.

If I use Kb3, this is what shown:

[image: Kb3]

I even tried to mount it manually but:

```
abhishek@abhishek:~$ neofetch
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               abhishek@abhishek 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           ----------------- 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Kernel: 5.4.0-42-generic 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Uptime: 8 mins 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Packages: 1871 (dpkg) 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Shell: bash 5.0.17 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Resolution: 1280x1024 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   DE: LXQt 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: Openbox 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM Theme: Lubuntu Arc 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Theme: Arc-Darker [GTK3] 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Icons: Adwaita [GTK3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Terminal: qterminal 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     Terminal Font: Ubuntu Mono 14 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      CPU: Intel Core 2 Duo E7200 (2) @ 2.411GHz 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       GPU: Intel 82945G/GZ 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         Memory: 663MiB / 2984MiB 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.                                       
                                                                   


abhishek@abhishek:~$ which lsblk
/usr/bin/lsblk
abhishek@abhishek:~$ /usr/bin/lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 149.1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   100M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0  51.3G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0    81G  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0  16.6G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   1    30G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1    30G  0 part /media/abhishek/USB DISK
sr0     11:0    1   4.3G  0 rom  
sr1     11:1    1   4.2G  0 rom  /media/abhishek/CONAN5
sr2     11:2    1     4G  0 rom  /media/abhishek/CONAN6
abhishek@abhishek:~$ which mount
/usr/bin/mount                                                                                                               
abhishek@abhishek:~$ cd /mnt
abhishek@abhishek:/mnt$ sudo mkdir dvd                                                                                       
[sudo] password for abhishek:                                                                                                
abhishek@abhishek:/mnt$ sudo mount -t udf /dev/sr0  /mnt/dvd
mount: /mnt/dvd: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sr0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
abhishek@abhishek:/mnt$ sudo mount -t iso9660 /dev/sr0 /mnt/dvd
mount: /mnt/dvd: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sr0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
abhishek@abhishek:/mnt$
```

Could anyone help me out as to what to do such that I can run the same dvd without copying to some other new dvd (as in this pandemic, no stores are functional to buy one) just read them on my Linux machine in the same way as windows 7 is reading it...

I do not know whether the discs are unfinalized or not but it works fine on Windows 7 but not on Ubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10 is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus off-topic on this site (refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic). Being EOL, mirrors can drop the release, and the main archive moves to old-releases.  Refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades  http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/07/19/ubuntu-18-10-cosmic-cuttlefish-end-of-life-reached-on-july-18-2019/

Comment: I don't know why you stuck with EOL 18.10 (where you using x86/32-bit? where the system could have been forced to 19.04; ISOs were built into the 19.04 cycle for Lubuntu & Xubuntu so package builds continued the life of 19.04), however now both 19.04 & 19.10 are EOL too, so a re-install is your best bet. If you were using x86/32-bit, I'd recommend going backwards to Lubuntu 18.04 LTS which is still supported.

Comment: As for your issue, some unfinalized data discs have no directory so contents may not be readable on other machine outside of the original writing machine/software. Some software packages wrote multiple directories (one for each write) which wasted space/reduced capacity of medium, so what you want may not be possible except through recovery (it'll depend on how disc was written & what software & settings were used in unfinalized write). If it was the windows 7 machine that wrote it; it'll have the missing info on it's HDD which is why it works on that machine (but won't usually on other win7)

Comment: @guiverc my question is now modified. please unmark it as being off topic